# Calling client side URL from browser without opening new page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, client-side

I'm trying to create a button that will dial an IP Phone by visiting a URL string:

```
http://admin:password@192.168.0.20/cgi-bin/ConfigManApp.com?Id=34&Command=1&Number=0123456789
```

When entering directly into the browser, the page returns a 1 and dials the IP phone.

On my website I can create a simple  link that when clicked, visits this page in a new window.

Is there any way of visiting this page without the user seeing that it opens?

Comment: These two guys beat me to it... XHR (AJAX) is the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

Sure you can use an AJAX call:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    var response = xmlhttp.responseText; //if you need to do something with the returned value
  }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://admin:password@192.168.0.20/cgi-bin/ConfigManApp.com?Id=34&Command=1&Number=0123456789",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) makes this even easier:

```
$.get("http://admin:password@192.168.0.20/cgi-bin/ConfigManApp.com?Id=34&Command=1&Number=0123456789")
```

Edit: since you are traveling across domains and can't use CORS, you can open the link using javascript and them immediately close the window. Example below:

```
document.getElementById("target").onclick = function(e) {
    var wnd = window.open("http://admin:password@192.168.0.20/cgi-bin/ConfigManApp.com?Id=34&Command=1&Number=0123456789");
    wnd.close();
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had tried this but I'm getting an error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah you didn't mention that this was a cross-domain request. AJAX calls will not work if the requesting domain doesn't match the requested resource. You will need to setup a [CORS header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) if you want to use AJAX.

Comment: If that is unacceptable then the only idea I have left is to open the the window using javascript and then immediately close it.

Comment: Genius - that's a great fix for now! I didn't realise you could close a new window! Thanks for your help.

Comment: This didn't work on my phone, which didn't accept the headers and I couldn't figure out how to send the right ones.

Answer (score 2):

You would use an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

```
function dialResponse() {
 console.log(this.responseText);//should be return value of 1
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = dialResponse;
oReq.open("get", "http://admin:password@192.168.0.20/cgi-bin/ConfigManApp.com?Id=34&Command=1&Number=0123456789", true);
oReq.send();
```

This will be semi-hidden. However, it is still issued client side so they will see it occur in the network record. If you want this to be truly hidden, you would have to do it server side.

Answer (score 1):

This javascript will call it in the background without displaying anything:

```
<script src="javascript">
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "http://admin:password@192.168.0.20/cgi-bin/ConfigManApp.com?Id=34&Command=1&Number=0123456789", true);
xhttp.send();
<script>
```

Sure, it will be still visible in the console if you analyze the site. You could use a server-side script like PHP if you want to call it without trace like:

```
<?php
$response=file_get_contents("http://admin:password@192.168.0.20/cgi-bin/ConfigManApp.com?Id=34&Command=1&Number=0123456789");
```